# Nested Slideshow breaking with less than three slides

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm using the [bxslider](http://www.bxslider.com). I'm trying to nest two slide shows into one another. It works if I have more than two slides but not on any other configuration. I would like to stick with bxslider because it's so customizable.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63srT/) for the broken one.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fe29p/) for the one that works.